# Generating image in elixir with text

Tags: imagemagick, elixir, phoenix-framework, mogrify

I would like the same what this post is asking for: [Generating initials avatar with Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395381/generating-initials-avatar-with-elixir)
The answer to use Mogrify is not very helpfull. I already got https://github.com/zamith/mogrify_draw/ but it is not generating the text I want.
The examplecode

```
%Mogrify.Image{path: "test.png", ext: "png"}
  |> custom("size", "280x280")
  |> canvas("white")
  |> custom("fill", "blue")
  |> Mogrify.Draw.circle(140,140,100,100)
  |> custom("fill", "yellow")
  |> Mogrify.Draw.circle(140,140,140,100)
  |> create(path: ".")
```

is creating the image with the circles.

I tried

```
%Mogrify.Image{path: "test.png", ext: "png"}
 |> custom("size", "280x280")
 |> canvas("white")
 |> Mogrify.Draw.text(10, 10, "Text")
 |> create(path: ".")
```

but this is only creating a blank white picture. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to set the color to fill (`custom("fill", "black")` or like,) otherwise the text is drawn in white.

Comment: I tried black before and had a black image without any text.
      |> custom("fill", "black") has no effect. Could you provide me some code instead of downvoting?

Comment: Oh, indeed, it should be `custom("stroke", "black")`, not `"fill"` of course.

Comment: @Sardoan your example works well for me - http://joxi.ru/brRw53UJReGgm1. Can you provide some repo to reproduce the problem?